how can i remove the transparency of the scroll bar in monaco editor?
I don't want the text to be seen behind the scrollbar. Maybe with some margin? I tried this:
 <Editor
    height="100%"
    defaultValue={''}
    theme={mode === 'dark' ? 'vs-dark' : 'light'}
    language="html"
    value={props.value ?? ''}
    onChange={handleChange}
    options={{
      minimap: { enabled: false },
      lineNumbersMinChars: 2,
      readOnly: props.readOnly,
      scrollbar: {
        backgroundColor: mode === 'dark' ? '#333' : '#f0f0f0',  
        sliderBackground: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5)', 
        activeSliderBackground: 'rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.8)',
      },
      padding: { right:100 },
      margin: { right:100 },
      alwaysConsumeMouseWheel: true,
    }}
    onMount={handleEditorMount}
  />



To remove the transparency from the navigation bar in Monaco Editor, you would need to modify the CSS or the relevant styles that apply to the editor's layout.
The Monaco Editor doesn't provide a direct option for controlling the transparency of its navbar (if you’re referring to the UI elements like the toolbar or editor area), but you can apply custom styles to remove or change transparency.
